# How reliable must a regressor be for data imputation?

Tags: regression, random-forest, data-imputation

I have a dataset that seemingly has missingness not at random and am thinking on using regressor to fill the missing values. I know that complete case analysis is on the table; however almost 20% observations of the variable of interest is missing and therefore excluding them entirely seems to be a bad choice.

I run Random Forest for this and obtain R-squared score of 0.82, which is pretty high. However, I'm not sure whether this will be adequate enough to fill the missing data.

Any opinion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is not to rely on a single imputation of each missing data point, but rather to acknowledge the uncertainty in imputation and take it into account. In [multiple imputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-imputation/info) you construct several sets of imputations on the data, perform your analysis on each of the imputed sets, then combine information from the analyses. Thus the results include both uncertainty from the model itself and that from the uncertainty in imputation.

From that perspective any reliability of the "regressor" or other imputation scheme will do. You just will get sharper final estimates the better the imputation works at reconstructing the data.

I'd recommend looking at Stef van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/). In particular, do you use "missingness not at random" (MNAR) in its specific technical meaning? If so, then single imputations are certainly not a good idea.

Sometimes people use that terminology to represent data that are not "missing completely at random" (MCAR). There is a technical "missingness at random" (MAR) that is a less demanding assumption than MCAR but still allows for straightforward multiple imputation. If your data are MNAR in the technical sense then your problem is more difficult. See [this explanation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-MCAR.html) from van Buuren:

> [MCAR] effectively implies that causes of the missing data are unrelated to the data. ... If the probability of being missing is the same only within groups defined by the observed data, then the data are missing at random (MAR). MAR is a much broader class than MCAR. ... MAR is more general and more realistic than MCAR. Modern missing data methods generally start from the MAR assumption. ... If neither MCAR nor MAR holds, then we speak of missing not at random (MNAR).   ... MNAR is the most complex case. Strategies to handle MNAR are to find more data about the causes for the missingness, or to perform what-if analyses to see how sensitive the results are under various scenarios.

Multiple imputation tools, including several schemes for doing the imputation, are available for example in van Buuren's [mice package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=mice) in R.

Comment: I have a stupid idea of using MCMC for imputation so that the posterior distribution of a parameter is more normally distributed. I was thinking that RF is multiple imputation because of the bagging method it uses. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @daddymaterial I don't offhand see a reason why you couldn't use multiple MCMC samples as imputation sets to analyze separately and then combine. Or consider the approach of the `mice.impute.norm()` function in the `mice` package, which imputes via Bayesian linear regression. The functions in `mice` have been developed and refined for over 20 years now, providing a wealth of experience to draw from.

Comment: followup: I tried mice from here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/dealing-with-missing-data-using-r-3ae428da2d17 and my RStudio or jupyter notebook always freezes when I tried to impute the data. Whereas with python, I used Random Forest with bootstrap by one-hot-encoded all the categorical predictors and use them + continuous predictors to predict one column of data that I'm trying to impute. The result seems OK based on R-squared val. If I found that the missing data is proportional to the clusters that I'm trying to impute, would it be better to just ignore all the missing datapoints entirely?

Comment: @daddymaterial Ignoring the missing data is probably the worst way to proceed. It sounds like your random-forest imputation includes some randomness due to the bootstrapping, so it might be simplest and best to repeat that process several times to get multiple data sets differing in the imputed values, getting your coefficient estimates etc separately for each data set. Then use [Rubin's rules](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2727536/) to combine the estimates among the imputed sets.